# Unable to fetch title and message from push notification when app is in BACKGROUND

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am trying to build react-native app which has push notification implemented using react-native-push-notification. Now, when the app is in 'foreground', I am able to handle the notification.title and notification.message and displaying in an alert in the app (Through, PushNotification.configure's onNotification). When the app in in 'background', I am able to receive notification and when I click it, the app gets opened up or comes to the foreground. Here, I want to fetch the same notification.title and notification.message to display, but don't see these fields in notification JSON (notification.data is also empty). Following is the code from PushNotification.configure's onNotification:

```
    onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('NOTIFICATION:', JSON.stringify(notification));
        if (notification.foreground) {
          if(notification.userInteraction) {
            Alert.alert("Title:" + notification.title + " Message:" + notification.message);
          } else {
            PushNotification.localNotification({
              id: notification.id,
              autoCancel: true,
              title: notification.title,
              message: notification.message,
              vibrate: true,
              vibration: 300,
              playSound: true,
              soundName: 'default',
            });
            PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: notification.id});
          }
        } else {
          console.log("notification.data:", JSON.stringify(notification.data));
          if(notification.userInteraction) {
            console.log("Showing modal with notification details...");
          }
        }
      },
```

Thank you for your time to look into this.

Comment: When the notification is from the background you can see other props like data? Only the title and message aren`t available?  Because on background you may be in quit state, so you need call onNotification() only when you have a mounted component. If it's called too soon (e.g. within a class constructor or global scope), the notification data may not be available

Comment: So, here is the JSON I am receiving based on app's placing:
background:
{"foreground":false,"google.delivered_priority":"normal","google.sent_time":1602792622279,"google.ttl":2419200,"google.original_priority":"normal","from":"736...","google.message_id":"0:160...","collapse_key":"com.abc","data":{}}

foreground:
{"foreground":true,"userInteraction":false,"id":"-899701097","data":{},"color":null,"sound":null,"title":"test title","message":"test msg"}

I am looking for title and message for background app too.